# Cannot select: t11: f64 = fpow t9, ConstantFP:f64<-1.666667e-01>

Tags: llvm, clang++, dpc++

We are getting below error when we are trying to compile dpc++ code using clang++ compiler.

Error message:

```
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: t11: f64 = fpow t9, ConstantFP:f64<-1.666667e-01>
  t9: f64 = fma t8, t8, t6
    t8: f64,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:f64 %117
      t7: f64 = Register %117
    t8: f64,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:f64 %117
      t7: f64 = Register %117
    t6: f64 = fmul t5, t5
      t5: f64,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:f64 %118
        t4: f64 = Register %118
      t5: f64,ch = CopyFromReg t0, Register:f64 %118
        t4: f64 = Register %118
  t10: f64 = ConstantFP<-1.666667e-01>
In function: _ZN4quda8IdEEvRNS_6_7_EELi3EEES3_
llvm-foreach:
clang-15: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)    
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/compiler/build/bin
clang-15: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating pre-processed source(s) - no pre processable inputs.
make: *** [Makefile_all.dpct:1186: libquda.so] Error 1
```

Help and guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you reported problem to dpc++ (https://github.com/intel/llvm/issues)?

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide us with the sample code with steps to reproduce the issue along with your OS details to investigate more on your issue?